# Error while running web3 instance

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain

I have a 2 node Ethereum system already setup. I am trying to have a web3 client talking to it. I installed web3 on a client machine and it gave no errors.

However, I try to setup index.js and do node web3. It gives me an error.

This is the error I see:
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://172.17.0.5:8545") = web3;
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'HttpProvider' of undefined

Basically, this means it is unable to pick up any of the web3 providers. I tried with WebSocketProvider and IPCProvider, but still see this issue.

any inputs on what the issue could be.

thx - Anand

Comment: If you share JavaScript code it will be helpful for us to understand your issue

Comment: I've not written any code yet. Just installed web3 and want to connect to a geth instance I have on another machine.

Comment: In the index.js file in the web3 folder, I wrote the following -

Comment: var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://172.17.0.5:8545"));

Comment: Try to connect to ethereum node using metamask.

Comment: Ok. I tried with web3.js since this is a server application that will talk to the ethereum network using web3.js. I will anyways try this with metamask as well and see if it works.

Comment: @SohamLawar, looks like there may be some connectivity issue due to which metamask is not able to connect to the geth node at all. Either ways, from the error I see when I do: node web3,  I suspect there is also some syntax error here. It looks like it is not able to find Web3.providers at all.

Comment: another point I noticed: though I didn't get any errors while installing web3, I later got an error when I ran npm ls web3:   root@23588ddc4e65:/node_modules/web3/src# npm ls web3
web3@1.0.0-beta.36 /node_modules/web3
`-- (empty)

npm ERR! code 1

Comment: above error tells me something may be wrong with the installation of web3 itself.

Comment: I made a basic mistake. I wasn't familiar with how node JS works in general and started editing the indx js file in the web3 folder. That caused the problem for obvious reasons. my earlier understanding was the web3 functionality is stored in some library.

Answer (score 0):

Add these parameters to your `geth` process:

```
--rpc 
--rpcapi web3,eth,personal,miner,net,txpool
--rpcaddr 172.17.WHATEVER
```

Note, that this is for tests only, and it is not a safe configuration, because the accounts are exposed

Comment: Didn't work. i in fact did a telnet from the client machine where web3 is installed to the geth node IP, port number (same as the IP/port I included in the index.js) and that worked.